# Tools for developing JAX-RPC WebService for WebSphere 7.0

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, jakarta-ee, websphere

I am new to web service development. I need to create a sample JAX-RPC application that can run on Web Sphere 7.0. I tried developing with eclipse Juno with WebSphere 7.0 Development tools plugin. When I try to create a service from a java bean eclipse does not show IBM jax-rpc runtime. It only shows jax-ws runtime from WebSphere and Apache Axis runtimes. Is there any other tool for developing Jax-rpc with websphere similar to tools for weblogic? If we can develop with eclipse or using command line tools what is the way to do? Any links to tutorials will be good.

Comment: If you are new to Web Services, you should create JAX-WS not JAX-RPC. JAX-WS is next generation and now strategic over JAX-RPC. Check this [article series](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-tip-jaxwsrpc/index.html) which talks about differences in more details. If you really have to develop JAX-RPC you will find some info [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twbs_devwbsjaxrpc.html?lang=en)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember; you can create JAX-RPC web service only on EJB projects and not on web projects. Or the other way around. Please try as I don't have access to RAD or WAS 7.
Kindly note that WAS 7 supports JAX-WS 2.1, which as Gas pointed out, is preferred to be used. For more details; kindly review [WAS 7 info center's page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/cwbs_jaxws.html)